# How can I recognize closed questions in "Suggested Edits" review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, closed-questions

How can I recognize closed questions in the "Suggested Edits" review queue?

The problem arose as [I was reviewing a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64425333/revisions) and made a minor edit (in order to give to the editor some feedback) before accepting the edit.

Neither opening the question via "Suggested Edits" review queue nor opening "Improve Edit" mode indicates whether the question has already been closed.

I would like to avoid situation where, as a result of such minor edit on a closed question, the question would unnecessarily appear in the reopen queue.

It would be nice that the closing status would be shown both in "Suggested Edits" queue and in the "Improve Edit" mode.

Comment: Hi Heikki, after our discussion in the question I also opened a relevant Meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402197/suggested-edits-queue-should-indicate-if-the-question-is-closed

Comment: @Tomerikoo, great!

Comment: Not what you are suggesting, but related: *[Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen 1) Accepting a suggested edit is one decision. 2) Editing a suggested edit before accepting it is an additional decision. These decisions 1)&2) are taken without knowing that the question is closed. 3) Placing a closed question into the reopening queue is an additional decision which the Suggested Edit reviewer implicitly takes on the closed question. Mostly edits to the closed questions have been minor, just clarifying the question. Therefore, in this context I would rather suggest the possibility to "mark as major" the edits on the closed question.