# Suggested Edits queue should indicate (better) if the question is closed

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425333/python-why-showing-anything-on-terminal-except-path), the question was closed because of a typo in the code - no amount of editing will make it "openable".

Still, you can see from the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64425333/revisions) that it was edited **after** it was already closed. It was then approved and edited by a reviewer from the *Suggested Edits* queue, with good reason - I would probably accept that edit as well as it clears away some unnecessary comments by the author. **But I wouldn't accept it if I knew the question is closed**. Accepting this (rather) superfluous edit might move this question to the *Re-Open* queue with no good reason - as established before, it shouldn't ever be re-opened.

This raises the question ***shouldn't the suggested edits (on questions) indicate if the question is closed?*** This might give reviewers a different perspective on the edit - some acceptable edits should be rejected if the question is closed.

---

I would suggest something as simple as the following:

[image]

Assuming "experienced" users are already aware and would not edit closed questions, newcomers still might edit closed questions thinking they are doing good. This is why the "responsibility" passes over to the reviewers to stop this, and this is why they should be aware if the question is closed.

---

At first I was going to say that edits to closed questions shouldn't even enter the *Suggested Edits* queue and only OP should be able to edit a closed question, but that might be too limiting as sometimes a question in *Need of details or clarity* might still be clarified by a "stranger" and the cycle of *suggested Edit -> Accept -> Re-Open -> Accept* might work in this case.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [May we have a way to edit a closed question without bumping it into the review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325787/1364007)

Comment: "But I wouldn't accept it if I knew the question is closed" - ... why not? If the edits are good, they're good. Heck, maybe they make the question good enough to reopen it, but we have a separate queue to decide that. Having to worry about closed status in the edit review queue is just another burden you don't really need.

Comment: @Gimby well you raise a good point that's hard to argue with, but the way I see it: Why bother with editing a closed question with minor edits that wouldn't change the *meaning* of the question just for it to be passed on to the reopen queue to be someone else's burden...

Comment: @Gimby A Question gets **one** free ride to the reopen queue with the first edit. If the author at any later point can actually edit it into being OK, their opportunity is lost due to some superficial edit. Not that it matters in this case, but closed Questions should not be edited unless the editor thinks the Question becomes re-open-able :)

Comment: @Scratte has an excellent point. Also, why should an otherwise good edit go down as rejected and (possibly) penalize the editor just because the question is/ got closed?

Comment: @zcoop98 because he shouldn't have edited a closed question in the first-place if the edit is not meaningful...

Comment: And if the question is closed *while* an edit is pending?

Comment: @zcoop98 That is an unfortunate case. Often those edits are rejected. It would be preferable if the close voters were to approve the edit **before** closing the post. That way the editor will not get punished with a rejected edit. But, choose the Questions you edit wisely to avoid such risks. Pick ones that are fine and doesn't have recent activity. "Active today" is not a good choice. Other users are unlikely to begin other actions on such posts. Some will even have your edit rejected to push their own. That gets you a "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit." reject reason.

Comment: I say that as more of a hypothetical than something that's happened to me prior, but point taken. Related post: [Why is there not an edit-rejection reason to cover cleanups of off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307482/11047824)

Comment: @SecurityHound Yeah sorry for the confusion, the screenshot is actually a mesh-up of a random review with the close message from the question referenced... I agree with what you said with the slight objection that if the question was not closed, I might have approved it. True, it is not VERY meaningful, but it does improve the question (removing comments like *plz answer me, almightys*) - but doesn't make it openable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that **there is** an indication in the review if the question is closed, similar to the indication in a question's title if it is closed - `[closed]`:

[image]

#### **But only if the title was not edited!**

The above image shows an example review where indeed the title had `[closed]`. But I actually just approved an edit myself:

[image]

Only to find that [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487796/i-am-writing-below-regular-expression-in-python-but-i-am-only-allowed-write-in-s) is already closed... The timeline shows that the question was edited (by Ryan above, funny enough) at 17:46, closed at 17:47 and then had another edit proposed at 17:48. Which means that both by the time of the proposed edit, and by the time of my review the question was already closed. **But there was no indication in the review!**

This is very frustrating and I believe should be changed. [I opened another meta post about this as a bug.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402285/closed-does-not-show-up-in-the-review-if-the-title-of-the-closed-question-was)

---

Regardless, I still believe that ***the current indication is not enough*** and might get missed. I think having the same closed message as in the question itself, something more in the lines of what I suggested in the question, is both obvious enough and in-line with how the question looks.

Answer (score 18):

#### This is a good solution to the wrong problem

Stack Exchange shouldn't spend dev time adapting other features to work around the fact that non-OP edits send posts into the reopen queue.  They should simply make it not do that, because it's unintuitive and causes problems like this (and more: plenty of 2k+ users don't know it does this, so they edit closed posts too).

This would be less effort for a larger payoff.  [The data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398343/208273) show that edits can help reopen a post, but that it's unlikely for an edit from someone other than the OP to do so without also having an edit from the OP.  If such edits didn't send posts to the reopen queue, it would be easier to improve posts so that they could actually be reopened.

Comment: I agree with most. I actually wrote [this SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347101/571958) on the matter (to the question *Improving Review Queues*) basically saying that only OP edits should sent the post to Re-Open, don't know how much attention that got... I guess I'm just trying to find a solution for the smaller problem, at least until the bigger one is solved (which I have a feeling will take time...)

Comment: @bad_coder please see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/data#usage-1 for why I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @RyanM: I'm embarrassed to admit that I didn't know that about non-OP edits—nor did I know that a question only gets one chance in the _Reopen Votes_ queue, as mentioned in the comments above. I doubt I've edited too many closed questions, but I'm certain it's happened, and especially if there are edits I can make that will help the author _toward_ a good answer, while combining it with a suggestion for what additional information is still needed. I'll definitely be more aware of that!